# Sockets and Threading

Tags: python, multithreading

I am currently pulling stock data down from an api that I have access to. I am doing it in the following steps:

1. loop through a list of symbols/stocks one by one
2. create a socket connection and send the relevant message to the api
3. receive the data and separate it into lines until "!EndMSG!" is received at which point the data for that symbol is complete
4. convert the data (string) into a StringIO, then read it into a pandas dataframe and ultimately write the data to sql
5. Do the next symbol/stock

Relevant code snippet:

```
def readlines(sock, recv_buffer=4096, delim='\n'):
    buffer = ''
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(recv_buffer)
        buffer += str(data.decode('latin-1'))

    while buffer.find(delim) != -1:
        line, buffer = buffer.split('\n', 1)
        yield line

def main():
    syms = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GS', 'F']
    for sym in syms:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect((host, port))

        data = ''
        message = sym + #relevant api specific commands
        sock.sendall(message.encode())

        for line in readlines(sock):
            if "!ENDMSG!" in line:
                break
            data += line + '\n'

        sock.close()

        data = io.StringIO(data)
        df = pd.read_csv(data)
        df.to_sql(...)
```

I would like to incorporate threading into this so that I don't have to do one stock at a time. However what im not sure of is where/how to implement locks so that I don't risk getting data for incorrect stocks to incorrect variables etc

This is what I have so far:

```
import threading
from queue import Queue

q = Queue()
my_lock = threading.Lock()

def readlines(sock, recv_buffer=4096, delim='\n'):
    buffer = ''
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(recv_buffer)
        buffer += str(data.decode('latin-1'))

    while buffer.find(delim) != -1:
        line, buffer = buffer.split('\n', 1)
        yield line

def get_symbol_data(sym, sock):
    with my_lock:
        data = ''
        message = sym + #relevant api specific commands
        sock.sendall(message.encode())

        for line in readlines(sock):
            if "!ENDMSG!" in line:
                break
            data += line + '\n'

        data = io.StringIO(data)
        df = pd.read_csv(data)
        df.to_sql(...)

def threader():
    while True:
        sym_tuple = q.get()
        sym = sym_tuple[0]
        sock = sym_tuple[1]
        get_symbol_data(sym, sock)
        q.task_done()

def main():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((host, port))

    # create 4 threads
    for x in range(4):
        t = threading.Thread(target=threader)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    syms = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GS', 'F']
    for sym in syms:
        q.put((sym, sock))
    q.join()
    sock.close()
```

My attempt at incorporating threading simply hangs. No errors, nothing. It just hangs. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Im also not even sure if im using the lock at the right place?
btw, if I do not use a lock, the program still hangs. Presumably it should still work even if the data is all jumbled up because of not using locks?

Comment: Rather than using a different socket for each symbol, why don't you send all the messages over a single connection? Presumably there's no reason you need to wait for the response to one message before you send the next? You might want one thread to send the messages and one to read the responses, but that may be all you need. The slowness for this sort of issue is usually related to waiting for each response synchronously after the request.

Comment: In the `readline` function, your `while True` shoud never stop until, eventually, an exception is raised. Am I right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my 2*[small unit of currency]:

- What is the lock supposed to do? Now each thread has to wait for the lock before receiving data. This is not very efficient since the network operation is probably the thing that could benefit the most from being parallelized.
- Create a socket in each thread. This way, you don't need to synchronize access to the socket and maybe get rid of locks completely. Alternatively, use a socket pool.
- I'm not sure how you are storing your data, but you might need synchronization between writers when you are updating the pandas data frame. You mention SQL - hopefully your database takes care of that for you. Another option is to have the API/socket readers report their data to a second type of thread (or just the main thread) that collects/writes the data to your storage.

All of the above assuming that the network operations are the reason why you want to parallelize in the first place. Someone mentioned in the comment that you could reuse the socket for all symbols. I don't know how your API works, but it seems to me that this would require all symbols to be collected serially.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will give each point some thought. As to the reason I want to do this, it is because I am pulling data down for 5 000 stocks. So it is a lot of data. It seems to me to be inefficient to send the request for one stock, receive the data, write the data to db, then move to the next. Im trying to figure out a way to get through all 5 000 stocks faster.

Comment: Have you profiled your code? My guess was that it's the reading from the socket that takes the most time, but I guess it could also be parsing or writing to a slow database. If it's the network, a couple of threads taking items off a work queue (like in your implementation) would probably speed things up a lot, unless the problem is your bandwidth or the API's speed. The problem with your implementation is the locking, which basically removes the parallelism again.